# How do I prevent a timeout when connecting to Azure mobile services?

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am using an Azure mobile service API via the iOS MSClient object (invokeAPI).  I can successfully call the API most of the time, however on each initial call (to any of the services) I get a timeout.  I assume this is due to some spin-up time required to get the service up.  How do I set a timeout for the API on the iOS device?

I dug into the source for the iOS SDK and see its using a wrapper of NSMutableURLRequest which will take a timeout (but appears its not exposed on the SDK), but I have not found away to set an SDK wide timeout.  Does that exist?  Do I need to fork the API so that I can expose that ability?  Or did I just miss it?

Comment: Can you send you mobile service name so we can investigate to see what is going on? The service does take some time to spin off if it has been unloaded (which happens on free services), but the time should be in the order of ~15 seconds, which shouldn't trigger a timeout from the client request.

Comment: @carlosfigueira As soon as I mentioned it... its performed very well.  I gather there isn't away to tweak the client side without a fair bit of work?

Comment: @carlosfigueira I'm getting fairly consistent timeouts on different methods using invokeAPI.  I don't see errors in the azure server log...which suggests its purely client side.